# Jenkins failed to create process with tox and py.test

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest, tox

I'm running my `python setup.py sdist` at Jenkins shell

`Tox` is running and installs all dependencies but while getting to the `py.test` command if says():

```
py27 runtests: commands[0] | py.test --junit-xml=C:\my_folder\unit_test_results.xml
failed to create process.
```

my `ini` file looks like that:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27, docs

[testenv]
deps=pytest
commands=py.test --junit-xml={toxinidir}\unit_test_results.xml

[testenv:docs]
basepython=python
changedir=docs\source
deps=
    sphinx
    sphinx_epytext
commands=sphinx-build -W -b html -d {envtmpdir}\doctrees . {envtmpdir}\html
```

Any idea why it fails to create process?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Bruno Oliveira `win7`

Comment: Can you run py.test in cmd?

Comment: My guess is some installation issue when using the `py.test.exe` file created by distutils. Try to replace `py.test` with `python -m pytest` in your `tox.ini` file.